# Python win32com convert from xlsx/xls to xlsm?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I have seen many responses for win32com on how to convert from xlsm to xlsx or xls, but I am trying to do the exact opposite. I tried to mimic the code used to convert xlsm to xlsx but I get an error message. The code I'm using is:

```
import win32com.client as win32
from win32com import client
from shutil import copyfile

xlApp = client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

if file_original[-1] == "x" or file_original[-1] == "s": # If it is xlsx or xls
    file_temp = copyfile(file_orig, str(main_folder) + "\\mainfile_duplicated_nomacro.xlsx")
    books_temp = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(str(main_folder) + "\\mainfile_duplicated_nomacro.xlsx")
    books_temp.SaveAs(Filename = "\\mainfile_duplicated.xlsm" , FileFormat = 52)
    books_temp.Close(True)
elif anl_orig[-1] == "m": # If it is xlsm
    file_dup = copyfile(file_orig, str(main_folder) + "\\mainfile_duplicated.xlsm")
```

When I save books_temp, I use FileFormat = 52, which is something I got from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.XlFileFormat). The error message I get is:

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel',
>   "Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 'C:\EDF0B000'. There are
>   several possible reasons:\n\n• The file name or path does not
>   exist.\n• The file is being used by another program.\n• The workbook
>   you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open
>   workbook.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: _Where am I going wrong?_ Did you look at the possible reasons outlined in the error message?

Comment: How does *file_orig* differ from *file_original*? You may not want to copy an .`xls` (which can hold macros) to `.xlsx` format but also use `.SaveAs`.